# The meaning of "stocks" in “…successfully increasing stocks, whether by seed…”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What do you think the meaning of "stocks" is in this particular sentence:

> *Knowing how plants function and understanding their life cycle are vital to raising and maintaining healthy specimen, and to successfully increasing **stocks**, whether from seed or by other means.*
>
> Source: *[The American Horticultural Society A-Z Encyclopedia of Garden Plants](https://books.google.it/books?id=Xr4SAQAAMAAJ&q=%22and%20to%20successfully%20increasing%20stocks%22&dq=%22and%20to%20successfully%20increasing%20stocks%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)*

I think the meaning is "varieties, species", but I'll appreciate your comments. Also, to me, the plural form seems *interesting* because I thought that "stock" in the sense of "origin, descent" is uncountable noun.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: -1 no research. Quoted text not cited. Quoted text not linked to.

Comment: @Clare how about giving a little, tiny leeway to newcomers? Biyana quoted the sentence but left out the author, well it's not a thesis so as a first-time offence it can pass.  You could probably do everyone a favour and start being a bit more  "nice" instead of downvoting and carping. If you're bored with the site and with its questions, you're not alone, think of a good question to ask. Actually, the user formatted his question rather nicely...

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: 1 @Mari-LouA hey, I bother to [give a reason](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/downvoting-newcomers-with-no-explanation-or-comment) and I find I'm still not pleasing 
 everybody (i.e., you, I guess). 2 I would consider retracting my DV but can't verify you've added the correct source 3. Thanks for reminding me of the very good question I did ask, which was, imo,  wrongly closed and received a +16 answer by tchrist. After ennui over it I've decided to try to get it reopened.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Okay, my browser didn't do a good job of displaying the link you added, so I tried something else. Thank you for improving the question by providing a link.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant definition on Merriam-Webster is:

> [6 a: the equipment, materials, or supplies of an establishment
>
>   6 b: a store or supply accumulated or available;
>   especially :the inventory of goods of a merchant or manufacturer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stock)

In the sentence you provided, the meaning is that knowing how plants function and understanding their life cycle is important for increasing the amount of plants that the farmer has.

Answer (score -2):

One possibility is that it means the plants that are known as ***[stocks](https://www.gardeningdirect.co.uk/stocks-guide)***.

Comment: Unlike because this is an introductory sentence of a chapter called "The Life of Plants".

Comment: I downvoted this very short answer because it didn't even include a link. But then I clicked and on the bolded,  italicized word ***stocks*** and was surprised it actually was a link. Which is to say that on Mobile view, your link appeared like a regular ***bolded italicized word***. Then I looked at your formatting and edited it so that the hyperlink text shows up in Mobile view. However it's still an extremely short answer. Not sure it should be an answer. But with the site going to the birds, it's almost irrelevant.